# Number of elements of a prime ideal's coset

Tags: abstract-algebra

In $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, let

$$I = \{ f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\mid f(0)\text{ is an even integer}\}$$

Prove that $I= \langle x, 2\rangle$

Is $I$ a prime ideal of $Z[x]$? Is $I$ a maximal ideal? How
many elements does $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ have?

**My progress:** I was able to show the first three parts of the questions by using Ideal Test and definition of prime ideal. I think $I$ is not maximal ideal, because $\langle x,2\rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$, but not the other way around. I also  don't quite understand the use of the number 2 in the definition of I. But I'm stuck on the last part of the question for many hours, so I hope someone can help me with it.

Comment: Your definition of maximal ideal is not right. $I$ is a maximal ideal if the only ideal that properly contains $I$ is the whole ring; that is, $I$ is maximal if for any ideal $J$, $J \supset I$ implies $J = I$ or $J = \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Also, your statement that $I = \langle x, 2\rangle = f(x)+2g(x)$ where $f(0)=g(0)=0$ is not true either. For example, $2 \in I$, but then $f(0)+2g(0)=2$ shows that at least one of $f(x), g(x)$ is nonzero at $0$. Perhaps you meant $f(x) + 2g(x)$ where $f(0)=0$, i.e. $x|f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, you're correct! Many thanks for correcting my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try to understand how $I$ arises as the kernel of a map from $Z[x]$ to some suitable ring. (Use the first isomorphism theorem.)

Further hint: Consider some ring homomorphisms $Z[x] \to Z \to Z / 2Z$ (the first is the evaluation homomorphism). Is this is map surjective? Is the image a field? (This answers maximality.)

Comment: The image $Z/2Z$ is not a field, but it is surjective I think. However, I don't see how the image is a field or not helps answer the maximality question though:(

Comment: It is a field. What is the inverse of 1? It is helpful to know that an ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$ is maximal iff $R / I$ is a field.

Comment: $Z/2Z = 0+2Z, 1+2Z, etc = (2Z$ or $2Z+1) = Z$. But $Z$ doesn't have multiplicative inverse for EVERY non-zero elements (a is in Z but $a^{-1}$ is not in Z), so how come $Z/2Z$ is a field? And the inverse of 1 is any integer-coefficient polynomial f in $Z[x]$ such that $f(0)=1$.

Comment: :can you please help share your solution to the last part too(i.e, the number of elements part)?

Comment: There are only two elements in $Z / 2Z$, and the only nonzero one is $1 + Z$, which has an obvious inverse. The cosets of an ideal are the elements of the quotient ring, and the quotient ring given by modding out by the kernel is isomorphic to the image of the ring homomorphism. An isomorphism is in particular a bijection.

Comment: shouldn't $1+2Z$ rather than $1+Z$ be an element in $Z/2Z$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, thanks.

Comment: So, you meant we have $2$ distinct elements in $Z/2Z$? I see now that you're using the First Isomorphism theorem, since the mapping from $Z[x]$ to $Z/2Z$ is a homomorphism:)

Comment: Yes, that is what I was doing.